# APP_INITIALIZER undefined results after page reload

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple config service that I've wired with APP_INITIALIZER token in my app.shared.module.ts:

```
 ConfigService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) =>
                () => configService.getStuff(),
            deps: [ConfigService],
            multi: true
        },
```

This executes the subscription (config.service.ts):

```
settings: any; 

getStuff() {
    this.getSettings()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.settings = data);
        });
}

getSettings(): Observable<ISettings> {
    return (this.httpClient
        .get<ISettings>(this.localbaseUrl)
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.errorHandlerSerevice.handleError)
        )) as any;
}
```

Then I inject this service into other services (through their constructors - which I don't like) and everything works fine on the app start:

```
constructor(){
     this.settings = this.configService.settings;
}
```

Its fine when I go to the home page and refresh the app from there.
The logic is called and data returned. 
However when I refresh a particular page that uses the component and calls the constructor it seems to late for the data to arrive back, hence I get undefined returned here:

```
this.settings = this.configService.settings;
```

I guess the 'wire up' is wrong...

Any suggestions how to tackle it?

Comment: I believe you're following [Dave Bush: where to store angular configurations](https://medium.com/@davembush/where-to-store-angular-configurations-c5d5bb348743). one caveat he neglects to mention, is the fact that even with this recommendation,  you are still obligated to compile per-environment for the sole purpose of changing index.html's `<base href>` per environment. make sure you're not implementing that for nothing.

Comment: @Stavm Yes, I do compile per environment. Coming back to my original issue - frankly I am annoyed with (1) this implementation and (2) the lack of options I have here and (3) the fact that the Promise makes such a difference here and (4) the fact I cannot rely on the usual page life cycle. It is rather annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Angular to *wait* for your custom `APP_INITIALIZER` to complete, it must return a `Promise`. Your `getStuff` method isn't returning *anything*, which means Angular won't wait for `this.settings` to get set.

You can use [`toPromise`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) to convert your `Observable` into a `Promise`. Here's a basic example:

```
getStuff(): Promise<void> {
    return this.getSettings()
        .toPromise()
        .then(data => {
            this.settings = data;
        });
}
```